# How to open a link in loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages. I loaded my second page inside my first page.

In the second page i have a link.

The problem is, when I click on the link in the second page, it opens in new tab.

How do I open this link in same page, like an `iframe`?

Here is my snippet:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#second').load('second.html');
});
```

```css
#second{width:100%; height:300px; border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>First page</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="second"></div>
<!-- 
THis is my second page code ////////
<html>
<head>second page</head>
<body>
<a href="google.com">click here !</a>
</body>
</html>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, you cannot open Google in a frame

Comment: similar to https://jsfiddle.net/mrid/uwva4su8/ but you cannot control link clicks of the embeded page.

Answer (score 0):

Name your iframe `<iframe name="namedIf"></iframe>`

and then in your anchor tag use target attribute `<a href="link" target="namedIf"/>`

But as the comments says, google doesn't allow you to iframe their content in your site.

**UPDATE**

As you're not using iframes, the only thing i can think of is to "intercept" any clicks to the anchor tags present on your loaded document and use the same function again to load it.

```
$(function() {
    $('#second').load('second.html', function(){
        $("#second a").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#second").load($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
});
```

So the code gets executed when your code has completed loading `second.html` into your document.

Comment: google was a sample. i do not to use iframe. is there a way to open with link?

Comment: @stackbaz I think thats what you're looking for

Comment: Is it an own page that you want to load in first page or an external page?

Comment: @Finduilas it is an own page.

Comment: I should use an include in PHP, or jquery (.load() ) for this